# Display cross sells inside WooCommerce single products custom tab

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, product

I'm trying to display WooCommerce cross sells inside a custom tab in single product pages *(similar tab as "Reviews" and "Additional information")*. For that I tried using WooCommerce function:

```
woocommerce_cross_sell_display();
```

But it doesn't work (I receive no error and no visual result).

Here is what I tried so far:

```
//Add custom tabs filter
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'add_new_default_product_tab' );
function add_new_default_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    global $product;

    // set the new priority to the "reviews" tab
    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 20;

    // gets the value to use as the title and slug of the new tab
    $custom_tab_title = "אביזרים";
    $custom_tab_title2 = "אביזרים משלימים";

    // if the custom field is set, it adds the new tab
    if ( ! empty($custom_tab_title) ) {
        $tabs['awp-' . sanitize_title('props')] = array(
            'title' => 'אביזרים',
            'callback' => 'awp_custom_woocommerce_tabs',
            'priority' => 5
        );
    }
    if ( ! empty($custom_tab_title) ) {
        $tabs['awp-' . sanitize_title('additional-props')] = array(
            'title' => 'אביזרים משלימים',
            'callback' => 'awp_custom_woocommerce_tabs2',
            'priority' => 10
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
}
 
    //Callback to display upsells (WORKS)
    
    function awp_custom_woocommerce_tabs($key, $tab) {
         woocommerce_upsell_display( 3,3 );
    }
    
    
    //Callback to display cross sells (Doesn't work)
    
    function awp_custom_woocommerce_tabs2($key, $tab) {
        woocommerce_cross_sell_display();
    }
```

Its wired because upsells working fine, but cross sells (which basically is the same) doesn't work.

How to display cross sells inside WooCommerce single product pages custom tab?

[Link to my website](https://vps1420.secured-cloud.net/product/test/#tab-awp-additional-props)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Product cross sells are for cart and some changes in [`woocommerce_cross_sell_display()` function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2065-L2104) are required, to get it work in product single pages.

This can be done cloning the code from that function in a custom function and changing [this line](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2080):

```
$cross_sells = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_get_product', WC()->cart->get_cross_sells() ), 'wc_products_array_filter_visible' );
```

with

```
$cross_sells = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_get_product', $product->get_cross_sell_ids() ), 'wc_products_array_filter_visible' );
```

So your final code is going to be:

```
// Add custom tabs filter
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'add_new_default_product_tab' );
function add_new_default_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    global $product;

    // set the new priority to the "reviews" tab
    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 20;

    // gets the value to use as the title and slug of the new tab
    $custom_tab_title = "אביזרים";
    $custom_tab_title2 = "אביזרים משלימים";

    // if the custom field is set, it adds the new tab
    if ( ! empty($custom_tab_title) ) {
        $tabs['awp-' . sanitize_title('props')] = array(
            'title' => 'אביזרים',
            'callback' => 'woocommerce_upsell_display_in_tab',
            'priority' => 5
        );
    }
    if ( ! empty($custom_tab_title) ) {
        $tabs['awp-' . sanitize_title('additional-props')] = array(
            'title' => 'אביזרים משלימים',
            'callback' => 'woocommerce_cross_sell_display_in_tab',
            'priority' => 10
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
}

// Callback to display upsells
function woocommerce_upsell_display_in_tab() {
     woocommerce_upsell_display( 3, 3 );
}


// Callback to display cross sells
function woocommerce_cross_sell_display_in_tab( $limit = 3, $columns = 3, $orderby = 'rand', $order = 'desc' ) {
    global $product;

    $cross_sells = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_get_product', $product->get_cross_sell_ids() ), 'wc_products_array_filter_visible' );

    wc_set_loop_prop( 'name', 'cross-sells' );
    wc_set_loop_prop( 'columns', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cross_sells_columns', $columns ) );

    // Handle orderby and limit results.
    $orderby     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cross_sells_orderby', $orderby );
    $order       = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cross_sells_order', $order );
    $cross_sells = wc_products_array_orderby( $cross_sells, $orderby, $order );
    $limit       = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cross_sells_total', $limit );
    $cross_sells = $limit > 0 ? array_slice( $cross_sells, 0, $limit ) : $cross_sells;

    wc_get_template(
        'cart/cross-sells.php',
        array(
            'cross_sells'    => $cross_sells,

            // Not used now, but used in previous version of up-sells.php.
            'posts_per_page' => $limit,
            'orderby'        => $orderby,
            'columns'        => $columns,
        )
    );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below code.

```
//Add custom tabs filter
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'add_new_default_product_tab' );
function add_new_default_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    global $product;

    // set the new priority to the "reviews" tab
    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 20;

    // gets the value to use as the title and slug of the new tab
    $custom_tab_title = "אביזרים";
    $custom_tab_title2 = "אביזרים משלימים";

    // if the custom field is set, it adds the new tab
    if ( ! empty($custom_tab_title) ) {
        $tabs['awp-' . sanitize_title('props')] = array(
            'title' => 'אביזרים',
            'callback' => 'awp_custom_woocommerce_tabs',
            'priority' => 5
        );
    }
    if ( ! empty($custom_tab_title) ) {
        $tabs['awp-' . sanitize_title('additional-props')] = array(
            'title' => 'אביזרים משלימים',
            'callback' => 'awp_custom_woocommerce_tabs2',
            'priority' => 10
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
}

//Callback to display upsells (WORKS)

function awp_custom_woocommerce_tabs($key, $tab) {
    ?>
    <div class="related">
    <?php
    // Customised: Show cross-sells on single product pages, under the attributes and short description
    global $post;
    $crosssells = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_upsell_ids',true);
    if($crosssells) { 
        echo '<h2>Up Sell products</h2>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($crosssells as $item) {
            // WP_Query arguments
            $args = array (
                'p'           => $item,
                'post_type'   => array( 'product' ),
                'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
            );
            // The Query
            $crosssells_products = new WP_Query( $args );
            // The Loop
            if ( $crosssells_products->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $crosssells_products->have_posts() ) {
                    $crosssells_products->the_post();
                    ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li>
                    <?php
                }
            } else {
                // no posts found
            }
            // Restore original Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}


//Callback to display cross sells (Doesn't work)

function awp_custom_woocommerce_tabs2($key, $tab) {
    ?>
    <div class="related">
    <?php
    // Customised: Show cross-sells on single product pages, under the attributes and short description
    global $post;
    $upsell = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_crosssell_ids',true);
    if($upsell) { 
        echo '<h2>Cross Sell products</h2>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($upsell as $item) {
            // WP_Query arguments
            $args = array(
                'p'           => $item,
                'post_type'   => array( 'product' ),
                'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
            );
            // The Query
            $upsell_products = new WP_Query( $args );
            // The Loop
            if ( $upsell_products->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $upsell_products->have_posts() ) {
                    $upsell_products->the_post();
                    ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li>
                    <?php
                }
            } else {
                // no posts found
            }
            // Restore original Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```